# Finding an inflection point between two conditions

Tags: regression, linear-model, multilevel-analysis, piecewise-linear, segmented-regression

The figure below illustrates a sample data from a numerosity estimation experiment with an uncalibrated (i.e., spontaneous) estimation condition (blue) and a calibrated estimation condition (orange).

[image]

As observed, there is resistance to change (significant overlap between the orange and blue data points) for the relatively smaller numerosities, but not for the larger numerosities. I am interested in finding the point at which participants change their estimates as a result of the calibration.

An approach is to treat each numerosity presented categorically and perform t-tests of the raw/trial-level estimates between the two conditions for each numerosity. Following that, I note the numerosity for which there is a significant difference.

However, the numerosities should be treated as a continuous variable rather than a discrete one. Hence, I would like to know if anyone has any suggestion on how to find the inflection point if I were to treat the numerosities as continuous such that the inflection point could be anywhere between the data points seen in the figure. The goal is to examine individual differences in the point of inflection.

I'm thinking along the lines of piecewise/segmented regression, but the inflection point using such a model pertains to one condition at a time rather than considering both conditions simultaneously.

I would appreciate any suggestions, or even comments on the reasonableness of such a question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The sequential t-test approach is contraindicated by theory: it has a good chance of giving invalid results. Your visualization might be deceiving you in how it obscures behavior at smaller values.  Consider reproducing this plot on square root scales. Could you explain how the error bars are computed and describe the data they are based on?